# NRVO Bug in Debugger in MSVC 17.4

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I ran across what appears to be a debugger bug with NRVO in debug mode. MSVC has apparently decided to enable NRVO in version 17.4, the latest release. This breaks the debugger's ability to display object contents.

Failure can be seen single stepping through `foo()`. `ret.filename` is not displayed.

```
#include <string>
struct A {
    std::string filename;
    // other stuff
};

A foo()
{
    A ret;
    ret.filename = "test";
    //return std::move(ret);    // debugger works with move return
    return ret;                 // debugger fails to show filename
}

int main()
{
    A x = foo();
}
```

Adding the option /Zc:nrvo- to the debug options makes the debugger work as does adding `std::move` to the return statement. But that imposes a performance hit. Is this a known debugger bug in 17.4?

Here's a link to a Microsoft discussion of adding NRVO to the debug mode.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/improving-copy-and-move-elision/

Comment: "*This breaks the debugger's ability to display object contents.*" In what way?

Comment: do you mean nrvo for all the nvro in the question?

Comment: @NicolBolas Debugger doesn't show values in `ret` but shows trash or can't access when single stepping until after returning from the function.

Comment: I suggest you create a ticket on [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp). I couldn't find one there yet for this issue.