# Visual Studio no displays the correct length of std::vector

Tags: c++, debugging

I have this piece of code when I try to debug it to see how many elements there are in `std::vector` then Visual Studio writes that the length of the vector is zero and I do not know how to fix it
(I build in DEBUG mode)

```
auto foo()
{
    std::vector<int> bar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return bar;
}
int main()
{
    foo();

}
```

[image: screenshot]

At first, I thought it was in the IDE, I tried to use Clean, but the result did not change, I decided to reinstall MSVC because I thought it was in it and I didn't come to anything either.

Comment: Is this a debug build or a release build? If it is a release build with compiler optimizations active, then the compiler may be smart enough to see that you are not using the return value, so that it removes all code that creates the value that is not being used.

Comment: Are you debugging a debug build a release build?  If release, this is most likely the compiler optimizing the variable away since it is unused.

Comment: its a debug build

Comment: If you add before `return bar;` a line doing `std::cout << bar.size();` Does it change anything?  What value gets printied?

Comment: well size method have returned 5 as expected, but debugger says that bar size is 0

Comment: Try changing `foo();` to `auto v{ foo() };`, or changing `auto foo()` to `[[nodiscard]] auto foo()`, or just using the value returned by `foo()` somehow in `main`. As commented, the compiler may be optimizing code away. Or just check optimizations are turned off for debug builds (if it is what you want): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2022#to-turn-on-optimization-in-a-debug-build-configuration

Comment: This is a know bug in MSVC which recently started doing NRVO in the debug version by default. When it does that the returned value, which is actually instantiated in the calling function, is not visible to the debugger and gives false results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in MSVC.

[NRVO bug in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74422765/nrvo-bug-in-debugger-in-msvc-17-4)

Solution is to add `/Zc:nrvo-` to the c++ compiler's additional options at Properties->Debug->C/C++->CommandLine

```
// recent versions of MSVC2022
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
auto foo()
{
    std::vector<int> bar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return bar;     // in debug mode, bar has size 0 unless /Fc:nrvo- flag is added
}
int main()
{
    auto x = foo(); // x is shown properly
}
```